# Selecting Individual Ranges Simulataneously - Cntl Select

Tags: excel, vba

In a workbook I can select a range of cells and then hold down the Cntl key to select another range simultaneously and so on. After which I can perform some formatting function like merging those ranges individually, etc.

How can this be done in VBA using Cells()?  Like

```
Range(Range(Cells(x,y),Cells(x,y+3)),Range(Cells(x+1,y),Cells(x+1,y+3))).Select
```

But this just selects the whole `Range(Cells(x,y),Cells(x+1,y+3))` as if it were one big single range.

I've tried what I've shown above and the Union function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWktW.png)

Comment: Your example range is useless i.e. the ranges are of the same size and they are adjacent i.e. let's say x and y are 1 then `A1:D1` and `A2:D2`, then of course, it's `A1:D2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `Union` method get the reference of multiple ranges

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.Union method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm132112)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim rAll As Range
    Set r1 = Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(x, y + 3))
    Set r2 = Range(Cells(x + 1, y), Cells(x + 1, y + 3))
    Set rAll = Application.Union(r1, r2)
    rAll.Select
```

- Actually, you don't need to `select` the range.

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

- If you try to merge cells

```vb
    Dim rArea As Range
    Set rAll = Application.Union(r1, r2)
    ' You may use Union multiple times
'    Set rAll = Application.Union(rAll, r3)
    For Each rArea In rAll.Rows
        rArea.Merge
    Next
```

> Question: cleaner code as opposed to selected each range individually and repeating the format commands over and over

- Refactor the common part as a seperated Sub procedure

```vb
Sub demo()
    Range("B2") = "Hello"
    Range("B4") = "Goodbye"
    SetFormat Cells(2, 2).Resize(, 3)
    SetFormat Cells(4, 2).Resize(, 5)
End Sub
Sub SetFormat(rng As Range)
    With rng
        .Font.Color = vbBlue
        .Merge
        ' other formatting code
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but no.  I tried this.  I just end up with one large merged set of cells, Range(Cells(x,y),Cells(x+1,y+3)).  In the end I want two sets of merged cells, Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(x, y + 3)) & Range(Cells(x + 1, y), Cells(x + 1, y + 3)).  Back on the worksheet this is accomplished by holding down the Ctrl key when selecting the second set and before performing the merge operation (or any other formatting operation).  How do you emulate Ctrl selecting in VBA?

Comment: I guess you are looking for merging cells in a row. Pls try `For Each rArea In rAll.Rows`. Please edit your post to show what's the expected result? A screenshot is helpful.

Comment: I think I added an image or at least a link to one.  Also, I tried the For Each rArea thing.

Comment: `For Each rArea In rAll.Rows: rArea.Merge: Next` works well for it. If you can't get the expected output, please share the whole Sub code.

Comment: The reason I would like to do this is because I have several groups of cell ranges that I want to format all the same way.  I thought if I could select them all simultaneously using VBA like you can in Excel using the Ctrl key that it would be more efficient and/or cleaner code as opposed to selected each range individually and repeating the format commands over and over.

Comment: I've upload another snippet. I'm not sure if it is what are you looking for. `selected each range individually` you definitely don't need to select the range. I shared [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA] in my answer.

Comment: Okay,  So the code works as long as the ranges are not the same size and adjacent to each other.  If either of those things are not true it works otherwise it doesn't give the desired result:Dim rAll, rArea As Range
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Dim StrtRow, StrtCol As Long

StrtRow = ActiveCell.Row
StrtCol = ActiveCell.Column

   Set r1 = Range(Cells(StrtRow, StrtCol), Cells(StrtRow, StrtCol + 3))
   Set r2 = Range(Cells(StrtRow + 1, StrtCol), Cells(StrtRow + 1, StrtCol + 3))
   Set rAll = Application.Union(r1, r2)
    
    For Each rArea In rAll.Areas
      rArea.Merge
    Next

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to get the code to appear properly.

Comment: To avoid `repeating the format commands over and over` , you can refactor it as a seperated Sub procedure. I've updated my answer to show a sample. For your code, please use `For Each rArea In rAll.Rows` (Not rAll.Areas).

Comment: that latest snippet might do the trick I think.  Thanks.  Don't understand why the original one doesn't work when they are adjacent and same size though.  Weird.

Comment: The rAll.Rows instead of rAll.Areas does it!